# Should I include VB macros in source control with my project?

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, macros, visual-studio-macros

For a C# project, I make use of several Visual Basic macros in Visual Studio. I was just considering that these would be of use to other developers that work on the C# project.

The macros so far include [removing trailing whitespace on save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82971/how-to-automatically-remove-trailing-whitespace-in-visual-studio-2008), organizing `using` directives and removing unnecessary ones, and an override for `Ctrl-M Ctrl-O` that expands regions. Would it be reasonable for me to include this macro code with my C# project in [Subversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Subversion)?

I don't know if it's even possible for macros to be made available/work in Visual Studio just because you open a particular Solution file, and that might be too invasive since some of the macros override existing Visual Studio behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are more like "useful tools" rather than code that is part of your project. I would not put them in SVN as part of your C# project, but if you think they are useful enough to be used by other team members, you could set up another SVN project just for these types of tools. Then your other team members could use them at their desire.

I think you would have to save the macro code to a file, and then you could just check the file into SVN. Whenever you changed the macro code, you could just keep SVN up to date with the latest macro code.

Comment: Good suggestion.  I wondered about the generic nature of the macros I wanted to store with my particular C# project...

Comment: This is what I do with php -- I have several shared libraries and functions, both third-party and home-brew, that I keep in a separate svn project. Easy to organize and deploy :)