# Using Firebug dev tools

Tags: html, firebug

I am using Firebug and I keep getting the spaces with arrows and don't know how to get rid of them. I believe it is coming form the line spacing from the Visual Studio but not sure.

Does anyone know how to get rid of them?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The arrow actually indicates a tab. To turn off their display open the [HTML panel's options menu](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/HTML_Panel#Options_Menu) and uncheck the option *Show Whitespace*.

[image: Option 'Show Whitespace' within Firebug's HTML panel]

To automatically remove the trailing whitespace in Visual Studio there is an extension called [CodeMaid](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/76293c4d-8c16-4f4a-aee6-21f83a571496/), which [takes care of that](http://www.codemaid.net/documentation/#cleaning) as you can read in [an answer to another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11314642/432681).

Comment: If the answer was helpful for you, you may upvote or even accept it.