# How to prevent visual studio change my csproj formatting

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, formatting, csproj

I get the latest ver of the code from TFS and I add one class file to my project but when I compare my csproj with the server version there are some formatting on the file.

[image]

How can I prevent my vs to do this auto-formatting?

Comment: Why is this a problem?

Comment: @DanielMann too much diff in my commit, there should be only one line diff bcuz i've only added one file to project

Comment: Is it happening every time or when changed it stops? I'm asking that because we are not having this problem with VS. Is it a project created on an old version of VS?

Comment: It's originally from TFS merge issue

Comment: @Daniel B Has anyone else participated in this project? Do they use the same version of VS or with same settings or any other editors? Seems someone use different editors to edit the files and committed the changes before.

Answer (score 0):

This issue maybe caused by someone else using different editors or different settings with VS to edit the files that removed the blank space and blank lines for them automatically, and then committed/checked in the changes before.

For example, to remove blank space and blank lines in VS :

- [How to Remove Blank Lines in Visual Studio](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-remove-blank-lines-in-visual-studio1)
- [How to automatically remove trailing whitespace in Visual Studio 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82971/how-to-automatically-remove-trailing-whitespace-in-visual-studio-2008/11314642)

So, to prevent changing the format, you need to ask all the team members do not remove blank space and blank lines when they edit the project files. Or ask them to use the same editor with same settings.

Comment: @Daniel B Have you resolved the issue? Is the reply helpful for you? any update?